# LINQ within Razor to adjoining table

Tags: c#, linq, razor

I am inside a foreach loop of my model.  For every document I need to grab a note.  The note is linked by documentID in both tables.  I keep only getting Note type returned instead of the actual note.

```
@foreach ( var item in Model.document)
{
     <span>@item.Table_Note.Where(n => n.documentid == item.documentid).Select(s => s.note)</span>
}
```

The above just returns the object.  What am I doing wrong to be able to return the specific note from the table?

Comment: You need to return the value of something in the object because it's not sure what to do with complex types. Ex: s.note.Id

Comment: You should really be including the notes within your Model. The View shouldn't be doing any kind of data retrieval

Comment: What does the structure of the `Note` object look like? You need to probably overload the `.toString()` method on this object to return a string representation of it.

Comment: @doogle I agree, however sometimes time constraints force us to do things we would rather not do and find time later to make them the right way. ;)

Comment: @JamesWilson there is no excuse for intentionally creating technical debt. Especially when 'doing it right' takes all but 3 more minutes than 'doing it fast' The most you'd have to do is add a property onto the View Model and move the query logic from the View, to the Action.

Comment: @doogle We shall agree to disagree then.  Let us not forget one thing does not conveniently fit every scenario.  I know my time constraints and what it would take to change the model (there is no view model, the person who coded it used a model and many many viewbags.  rewriting the code and adding a view model at this point in time is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
@item.Table_Note.FirstOrDefault(n => n.documentid == item.documentid).note
```

This will fix your issue.

Alternately to handle null value you could use below as well:

```
@(item.Table_Note.FirstOrDefault(n => n.documentid == item.documentid) ?? new Table_Note()).note
```

Comment: I always forget to use FirstOrDefault.  Thank you. :)